# Electric field a height $z$ above an infinitely long sheet of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

Consider an infinitely long sheet of charge of width $L$ lying on the $xy$-plane, between $x=-L/2$ and $x=L/2$. The surface charge density is $\eta$. I derive an expression for the electric field $E$ at height $z$ above the centerline of the sheet.

I start by examining a straight line from $x=-L/2$ to $x=L/2$. For an infinitesimal charge element $dQ$ due to a ITM area element of the sheet $dA$ on this line, we have $\eta = dQ/dA\implies dQ=\eta dA=\eta dx$, since the straight line has area equal to its length. I find that the electric field $dE$ due to this $dQ$ at height $z$ is computed as $$dE=k\frac{dQ}{r}\cos\theta = k\frac{\eta dx}{r}\frac{z}{r}$$

where $r$ is the distance from $dQ$ to the point $z$. The electric is field is found by integrating this expression from $0$ to $L/2$ and multiplying by $4$. This follows from mirror symmetry arguments. The origin is placed at the midpoint, below $z$.

I am confused about the following. Why is it, that only the charge elements in this straight line parallel to the $x$-axis below $z$ contribute to the electric field? Certainly the entire sheet contributes to the electric field at $z$. Yet there is apparently no need to consider points on the plane  with non-zero $y$ components. It seems like we ignore a great deal of the charge of this sheet.

Answer (score 1):

$\eta dA$ cannot equal $\eta dx$, which you can easily see via unit analysis. In these types of problems, instead of tracking $dQ$, I prefer to use the explicit formulas from Griffiths:

$$\mathbf{E(r)}=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\iint_S \sigma(\mathbf{r'})\frac{\mathbf{r-r'}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|^3}dA'$$

where the integration takes place over "primed space", and the domain of integration is the entire surface for which $\sigma$ is non-zero. These types of integrals take a bit of getting used to, but I find them indispensable when solving such problems.

Try to set up this integral, and let me know if you need more help. I can certainly weigh in more.

Answer (score 0):

So, start by integrating Coulomb's law:
$$\vec E(\vec r)={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-L/2}^{+L/2}\eta {(\vec r-\vec r^\prime)\over|\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3}\; dx^\prime dy^\prime.$$
We have that:
$$\vec r-\vec r^\prime= (-x^\prime \hat e_x-y^\prime \hat e_y+z\hat e_z),$$
and
$$|\vec r -\vec r^\prime|^3=({x^\prime}^2+{y^\prime}^2+z^2)^{3/2}.$$
So that,
$$\vec E(\vec r)={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-L/2}^{+L/2}\eta{(-x^\prime\hat e_x-y^\prime\hat e_y+z\hat e_z)\over({x^\prime}^2+{y^\prime}^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\; dx^\prime dy^\prime.$$
Now the symmetry of the problem tells us that the $x,y$ components of the field cancel out so that there is only a non-zero $z$ component, mathematically, one can use the fact that the symmetric limits of integration will yield a vanishing integral whenever the integrand is odd, which is the case for the $\hat e_x$ and $\hat e_y$ terms; thus the integral reduces to:
$$\vec E(z)={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-L/2}^{+L/2}\eta{z\hat e_z\over({x^\prime}^2+{y^\prime}^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\; dx^\prime dy^\prime.$$
You can do this multi-integral easily by looking up the relevant integration formulae in a suitable reference table.